# How can I restrict gameobject from moving beyond line in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this red apple that needs to move only inside the green apple line. If it tries to move beyond line it will be stopped at the green line and can' move beyond. How can I do that?

[image: Picture for better understand]
This is the code I use to move a red apple.

```
 Camera mainCamera;
 float zAxis = 0;
 Vector3 clickOffset = Vector3.zero;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start()
 {

     mainCamera = Camera.main;
     mainCamera.gameObject.AddComponent<Physics2DRaycaster>();

     zAxis = transform.position.z;
 }

 public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
 {
     clickOffset = transform.position - mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(eventData.position.x, eventData.position.y, zAxis));
 }

 public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
 {
     //Use Offset To Prevent Sprite from Jumping to where the finger is
     Vector3 tempVec = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(eventData.position) + clickOffset;
     tempVec.z = zAxis; //Make sure that the z zxis never change
     /*
     Debug.Log(tempVec.x);
     if (tempVec.x < 90)
     {
         tempVec.x = 90;

     }
     if (tempVec.x > 310)
     {
         tempVec.x = 310;

     }
     */
     transform.position = tempVec;
 }

 public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use code for this use colliders on both sides.

Comment: It don't work , my apple move through it. If i create another apple and use apple 1 to push apple 2 to collider, apple 2 got stopped by collider, so collider work, it just don't work on my moving apple.

Comment: Okaye. Keep in mind that there is no approach to done this only the collider way is best and fast. Double check the colliders on moving apple. Add collider to moving apple as well as the big green apple.

Comment: Both have collider, It working well, I think my moving apple code make it pass through, that why if i push apple 2 to big green apple apple 2 got stopped but moving apple pass through.

Comment: Uncheck the Trigger checkbox on moving apple collider.And add Rigidbody on it and set body type to kinematic If it will not help then tell me then we will do another approach of raycasts.

Comment: the moving apple is the same as apple 2. Anyway I kinda fix it, If i change this code "transform.position = tempvec"  to  "Rigidbody.MovePosition(tempVec)", the moving apple now got stopped at the big green apple line. But if it hit other apple, other apple got push away. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I need those apple to pass through other apple but only stop at Big green apple line. After change to Rigidbody.MovePosition, it stop pass each other like before,

Comment: Then set others small apples isTrigger in their collider setting in inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the polygon collider with this (although it's a bit buggy). Then when you're dragging the apple you don't set the position but you set the velocity based on the difference between the mouse and the apple.

Unfortunately, high-velocity objects are not always resolved properly in Unity. In the case that unity doesn't always resolve the collision properly I recommend raycasting the difference from the apple to the cursor, if you get a hit instead of using the cursor position you can now use the hit position.

[image: Example of raycast]

NOTE: Make sure it's not normalized because you want the velocity to be more if the cursor is further away from the fruit.

Comment: Thanks, but i fix it by change this code "transform.position = tempvec" to "Rigidbody.MovePosition(tempVec)".

Answer (score 0):

You could add a mesh renderer onto the big green apple. Then in your script you can check for collision and make the small apple react to the collision the way you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, but i fix it by change this code "transform.position = tempvec" to "Rigidbody.MovePosition(tempVec)".